# Typescript generic inference - interface vs typeof function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following interface and function:

```
interface DispatchRequest<QueryStateData = any> {
  (requestAction: RequestAction<any, QueryStateData>): Promise<{
    data?: QueryStateData;
    error?: null;
    isAborted?: true;
    action: any;
  }>;
}

export function useDispatchRequest(): DispatchRequest;
```

Now, when using it like that:

```
const dispatch = useDispatchRequest();
const response = await dispatch(fetchBooks());
```

for some reason response.data is of type any, while it should take `QueryStateData` from `RequestAction`

Very interestingly, refactoring interface `DispatchRequest` to function works suddenly:

```
declare function dispatchRequest<QueryStateData = any>(
  requestAction: RequestAction<any, QueryStateData>,
): Promise<{
  data?: QueryStateData;
  error?: null;
  isAborted?: true;
  action: any;
}>;

export function useDispatchRequest(): typeof dispatchRequest;
```

Why is this any different, is this a Typescipt bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function in javascript is like an object, I mean you can get and set properties to functions.

An interface defines the shape of the object, even if it's a function.

In this example generic interface defines non-generic function, which has genericly-typed property:

```js
interface Example<T> {
  (a: number, b: number): number

  prop: T
}

const fn: Example<string> = Object.assign((a: number, b: number) => a + b, {
  prop: 'string',
})

fn(2, 2) // is not generic
fn.prop * 2 // error as `prop` is a string
```

I tried to write a generic function using the interface, but it seems to be a bad idea.

So to define function just use function types, I'd use `type` keyword instead of `declare` and `typeof`:

```js
type DispatchRequest<QueryStateData>(
  requestAction: RequestAction<any, QueryStateData>,
): Promise<{
  data?: QueryStateData;
  error?: null;
  isAborted?: true;
  action: any;
}>;

export function useDispatchRequest(): DispatchRequest;
```

Also, I think it's not necessary to write `any` in the `<QueryStateData = any>` as generic type can accept anything by default, and eslint will complain on `any` type. And I highly recommend to use eslint, it's not just making code safer and better, but helps to improve knowledge.

Comment: thx for your snippet. However there is syntax error I believe, I rewrote it to:
```ts
type DispatchRequest<QueryStateData = any> = (
  requestAction: RequestAction<any, QueryStateData>,
) => Promise<{
  data?: QueryStateData;
  error?: null;
  isAborted?: true;
  action: any;
}>;
```

but the outcome is the same as interface, data is not inferred, like for function and typeof variant

Comment: Regarding QueryStateData = any I believe it is necessary, otherwise this arg had to be always provided, TS complains without giving this. The point of my case is that I really don't want to pass QueryStateData to DispatchRequest, I wanna it to be inferred from RequestAction. It works for function but not for interface or type.

Comment: In your code in the comment you wrote a type like `type TypeName<Data = any> = () => {}`, this function is not generic. Place `<>` this braces to the left of `(` as such: `type TypeName = <Data = any>() => {}`. I want to say that to make generic function place <> before (), as close as possible.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works, however it is interesting that then you cannot pass generic to such a type. There is one case I cannot solve, it is related to this one, if you are interested to take a look at that one too, I would really appreciate it! here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65260260/typescript-inference-of-sibling-functions-generic-arguments