# Typescript inference of sibling function's generic arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to achieve the following inference:

```
type RequestAction<Data = any, TransformedData = Data> = {
  type: string;
  request: any | any[];
  meta?: {
    getData?: (data: Data, currentData: TransformedData) => TransformedData;
    [extraProperty: string]: any;
  };
};

function fetchBooks(
  x: number,
  y: string,
): RequestAction<{ raw: boolean }, { parsed: boolean }> {
  return {
    type: 'FETCH_BOOKS',
    request: {
      url: '/books',
      x,
      y,
    },
    meta: {
      getData: data => ({ parsed: data.raw }),
    },
  };
}

const query = useQuery({
  action: fetchBooks,
  variables: [1, '2'], // inferred from fetchBooks argument types
});
query.data // inferred from `fetchBooks` generic
```

I can achieve only one at the same time, never both. Here are my attempts:

1)

```
interface QueryState<QueryStateData> {
  data: QueryStateData;
  error: any;
  loading: boolean;
}

type Arr = readonly any[];

export function useQuery<
  QueryStateData = any,
  Variables extends Arr = any
>(props: {
  action?: (...args: Variables) => RequestAction<any, QueryStateData>;
  variables?: Variables;
}): QueryState<QueryStateData>;
```

This almost works, `data` is inferred automatically from `QueryStateData` passed to fetchBooks: RequestAction. Variables also partially work, but only partially. It seems to work fine, for example if `fetchBooks` arguments is `(string, number)`, then type for `variables` will be indeed `[string, number]` tuple. But for some reason if I set `variables: [1, '1']`, then it would still work as suddenly type from TS would be `(string | number)[]`, converting it to array of unions, for reason unknown to me, which is unacceptable, I want variables to be precisely `action` arguments, order sensitive.

2)

```
interface RequestCreator<QueryStateData> {
  (...args: any[]): RequestAction<any, QueryStateData>;
}

export function useQuery<
  QueryStateData = any,
  R extends RequestCreator<QueryStateData> = RequestCreator<QueryStateData>
>(props: {
  action?: R;
  variables?: Parameters<R>;
}): QueryState<QueryStateData>;
```

With this one though I can achieve perfect `variables` inference. Unfortunately `query.data` would be type of `any`, `QueryStateData` inference doesn't work for some reason in this case, it is not picked from `action` callback generic.

Please tell me which method is more correct, and how to adjust it to achieve both `variables` and `data` inference. Or maybe there is yet another method I didn't consider. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `RequestAction` and what is the type of `fetchBooks`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I edited my post to include simplified version s of those. Please note that RequestAction is type not interface because this is redux action which supports also FSA actions with payload, hence I used union there, but here I simplified the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a *single* type parameter for the action, which is similar to your second attempt.

```
interface RequestCreator<QueryStateData = any> {
  (...args: any[]): RequestAction<any, QueryStateData>;
}

// Gets the `QueryStateData` type from a `RequestCreator`
// (e.g. GetQueryStateData<typeof fetchBooks> is { parsed: boolean }).
type GetQueryStateData<T extends RequestCreator> = T extends RequestCreator<infer QueryStateData>
  ? QueryStateData
  : never;

// I'm just using declare here so TS is happy
export declare function useQuery<R extends RequestCreator>(props: {
  action?: R;
  // The parameter types of R
  // (e.g. Parameters<typeof fetchBooks> is [x: number, y: string])
  variables?: Parameters<R>;
}): QueryState<GetQueryStateData<R>>;

const query = useQuery({
  action: fetchBooks,
  variables: [1, '2'],
});
// inferred correctly as { parsed: boolean }
query.data;

useQuery({
  action: fetchBooks,
  // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. (expected)
  variables: [1, 1],
});
```

I think (based on anecdotal experience; please don't quote me on this) that TypeScript infers type parameters better when they directly correspond to parameter types (or types directly ‘contained’ in them, like the type of `action`). This is why the compiler was having trouble inferring the type of `QueryStateData` in your second attempt.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYBBAxsAlgewDsAeAEQENgyoBeKMgkAGigBUAnelAMzzYFsIAE3KUaUEWQB8YgN4AoKFFCQAXFDRscBAOYBuBVDYJkaNfRBQAPnQYBtALr7FAygH418xYu0RgE91AAFIIUZGoSzJiIbEYEfqFq7Jw8-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-NA85GOoeCsKSUB-lAkxkGAYAgHI5RgLwwCyfJimqQMQy9qMEkQIORAwEhFSEWhnY0oWZG8JIgRgLUYAtuKigWrZAQwMU46sPOUB-BwLg7BukCzm+sAGFFV43neVT-GQCUAi+m6peMwBTLM7K-rOtirFA6xbDszAHOoRw6PY6QGNx-w4GQmzvCgAQ5fFvg7CgTmSD0HZ0RARDTjBrFPvBMCSONfSYIQkkXHaYj2YOioGKFIxqCVZXfigvKdZoPV9WotgAIzMEiABMSL2HsnTpPoUVUaGQhQGtMTycArwWGQ-6xcqQEgaCXxyJtIDqj6-E7eWe0hdcBBHZ+5WLLyUUsJuUBInV2xsEiWmztGZmgygODaAQV3QKeSXQEizQ6Eid5XmUkDYEI7WKBd3W9agN33VAt2vXI736EAA)

Comment: That's simply amazing, thank you! I have one remaining issue to be solved, I would like to preserve QueryStateData generic in useQuery, because actually case is more complicated, this all inference is for people using Redux action creator libraries without need to use constants. Then sometimes they won't pass action. This is actual interface for `useQuery` - ```export function useQuery<R extends RequestCreator = any>(props: {
  type: string | R;
  action?: R;
  variables?: Parameters<R>;
}): QueryState<GetQueryStateData<R>>;``` Notice `type` which could be also string

Comment: So if someone uses action creator library, `type` is enough and this will work, inference will work for data from it. But, if someone doesn't, one would need to pass `type: string`. Then, one could pass `action` here to in some cases (it is optional actually), then again it will work. But often one could pass only `type: string`, then it would be cool to do for example ```const query = useQuery<number>({ type: 'FETCH_NUMBER' })```, then `data` would be type of `number`, not `any`. I tried to update your example but without success. Not fluent yet with `infer` and conditionals ;)

Comment: I probably solved the issue with an extra conditional type, I will post your solution with this small adjustment soon!

Answer (score 0):

This is final type, I updated slightly cherryblossom response to still allow passing custom generic to useQuery:

```
interface RequestCreator<QueryStateData = any> {
  (...args: any[]): RequestAction<any, QueryStateData>;
}

type GetQueryStateData<T extends RequestCreator> = T extends RequestCreator<
  infer QueryStateData
>
  ? QueryStateData
  : never;

export function useQuery<
  Data = undefined,
  QueryCreator extends RequestCreator = any
>(props: {
  type: string | QueryCreator;
  action?: QueryCreator;
  requestKey?: string;
  multiple?: boolean;
  defaultData?: any;
  dispatch?: boolean;
  variables?: Parameters<QueryCreator>;
}): QueryState<
  Data extends undefined ? GetQueryStateData<QueryCreator> : Data
> & {
  load: () => Promise<{
    data?: QueryState<
      Data extends undefined ? GetQueryStateData<QueryCreator> : Data
    >;
    error?: null;
    isAborted?: true;
    action: any;
  }>;
};
```